# When adding a Magnet link in Deluge how can I choose which files in the torrent to download?

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

If I click on some magnet torrent link, Deluge opens but I cannot choose which files in the torrent to download. If I save the torrent file on desktop and drag&drop it do Deluge, I have then an option to choose which files I want to download.

Is there some hack to have the same option when Deluge activates on some magnet url?

Comment: Now I understand the question Cas.

Comment: Using `aria2c --bt-metadata-only true magnet:[...]`, you can download the .torrent file for a magnet link, which you can then add to Deluge and save only the files you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a limitation of magnet uris vs torrent files. Magnet uris only contain the torrent's infohash and optional the tracker and torrent name, whereas a torrent file will also contain the metadata about the torrent's files. The only way to retrieve the torrent's metadata when using magnets is by connecting and downloading from a peer, which takes time.

In future workarounds for this may well be implemented but currently you will have to add the magnet, wait for the metadata from peers, then choose the files you wish to download.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few tutorials on how to get a .torrent file out of magnet link:  this seems to be the easiest:

http://magnet2torrent.me/

Simply copy the magnet link, it takes a few seconds, then lets you download the .torrent with all of the metadata.   Selecting certain files to download out of said torrent is only available if you set the torrent to FULL ALLOCATION instead of compact.  I tested it with a 2.3 gig torrent with about 17 files.  Works great.

Comment: This isn't an answer to what the asker is asking.

Comment: Still good info though